# Using `Async` keyword while returning a promise object

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am developing some Nodejs scripts and I have a question about the usage of async keyword in JS itself.

For example, consider that I have a function which returns a promise like this:

```
function myFunction () {
  ... some job
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const innerResult = await someHeavyJob();
    ... some job
    resolve(innerResultThatIsManipulated);
  });
}
```

And I can write it in another way of this:

```
async function myFunction () {
  ... some job
  const innerResult = await someHeavyJob();
  ... some job
  return innerResultThatIsManipulated;
}
```

But I have a question that if I am choosing the first solution, then am I allowed to use `async` keyword and is that recommended or not? For example, something like this:

```
async function myFunction () {
  ... some job
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const innerResult = await someHeavyJob();
    ... some job
    resolve(innerResultThatIsManipulated);
  });
}
```

To emphasize that this is an async method and is returning promise (not a simple object) in all paths of its code.

So, what is the recommended way to use?

Comment: in your first function you are trying to return a promise of another promise, there are doing redundance unnecesary

Comment: Async is a kind of Promise (syntactic sugar). So you can use what you personally prefer.

Comment: The first way is considered an anti-pattern because you're wrapping a promise returning function inside a promise constructor. The Promise constructor is meant to be used to convert non-promise returning asynchronous functions into a promise

Comment: Here you go: [Should I use Promises or Async-Await](https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789)

Comment: Take a look: [When NOT to use promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527292/when-not-to-use-promises)

Comment: For comparison: [Node.js: When to use Promises vs Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041462/node-js-when-to-use-promises-vs-callbacks)

Comment: The difference(s): [Difference of using async / await vs promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057110/difference-of-using-async-await-vs-promises)

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo I have added some lines (`... some job` and `innerResultThatIsManipulated`) to note that it is just an example and there is no redundancy. And according to other's comments, I know about the differences between Promise and async/await solution but my question is about adding async syntax suger while returning a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an anti pattern:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const innerResult = await someHeavyJob();
  // ... some job
  resolve(innerResultThatIsManipulated);
});
```

You should not create a new promise with `new Promise` when the constructor callback is going to create a promise itself and then call `resolve` with that (manipulated) promised result.

This really should be coded like this:

```
return someHeavyJob().then((innerResult) =>
  // ... some job
  return innerResultThatIsManipulated;
});
```

#### The difference

So after the above remark, your question really is about adding the `async` keyword to this function definition:

```
function myFunction () {
  // ... some job 1
  return someHeavyJob().then((innerResult) =>
    // ... some job 2
    return innerResultThatIsManipulated;
  });
}
```

Here are the main differences:

- If an exception is raised *before* `.then()` is called -- so in "some job 1" or while calling `someHeavyJob` -- then the `async` version will still return a promise (which has a rejected state), while the non-`async` version will raise that error.
- Also, the promise returned by the `async` version is *not* the one returned in the `return` statement. The one that `async` returns is a separate promise, one whose resolution is (planned to be) bound to the one you provide to the `return` statement.

You could take this difference away, by writing the non-`async` version like this:

```
function myFunction () {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    // ... some job 1
    return someHeavyJob().then((innerResult) =>
      // ... some job 2
      return innerResultThatIsManipulated;
    });
  });
}
```

Or, better, flattened-out to one chain:

```
function myFunction () {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    // ... some job 1
    return someHeavyJob();
  }).then((innerResult) =>
    // ... some job 2
    return innerResultThatIsManipulated;
  });
}
```

This better mimics what the  `async` version does: that one *ensures* to return a promise.

So, in conclusion, just adding `async` is not producing a function that is guaranteed to be behave in the same way. If your aim is to *always* return a promise, even when an error occurs while the function executes, then definitely go for `async`. But once you do, there are often good reasons to also use `await` syntax: it just makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) says:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function — a
>   function that returns an AsyncFunction object. Asynchronous functions
>   operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event
>   loop, **returning an implicit Promise** as its result. But **the syntax and
>   structure of code using async functions looks like standard
>   synchronous functions**.

By doing this:

```
async function myFunction () {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const innerResult = await someHeavyJob();
    resolve(innerResult);
  });
}
```

You're returning an implicit promise that returns a promise. You asked if it would be an interesting approach to get the code more readable, I believe it confuses more than it clarifies.

*(not even talking about the async function inside the promise inside the async function that actually contains only that promise that contains only that async function, the first one I talked about not the last one, I mean the second one, did you follow? Edit: you've actually edited that snippet, it was just for the example)*

MDN adds:

> The purpose of async/await is to simplify using promises synchronously

In my comprehension, an async function is an alternative a promise, not an extension per say. Therefore, it seems not wise to combine the two of them the way you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Of all examples you've shown, only the second one is correct. The reason behind that is that `Promise` is a constructor function (hence you use it with `new`) that takes a regular function, not another `Promise` as it's argument.

**Example 1**

The interpreter translates your first example into something like this (theoretically):

```
new Promise( new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }))
```

That's not what you want and also considered an anti-pattern. Instead, you want this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })
```

Furthermore, it seems you already have a function (`someHeavyJob`) that results in a `Promise`. Why do you want to wrap it up in another `Promise`? Just use the `.then` method of the `Promise` returned by `someHeavyJob` to transform whatever it gives you.

In the end, you are left with something like:

```
function myFunction() {
  // ... some job
  return someHeavyJob().
    then( result => {
      // ... some job with result
    })
}
```

**Example 3**

The third example is incorrect for the same reasons example 1 has been incorrect, speaking from a technical as well as from a logical point of view.

**General rules of thumb**

Don't use `async` and `await` (only) as a means to communicate that certain functions are asynchronous in nature to other people (or your future self). Both keywords have implicit effects on the code you write and make it behave different.

Try to stick to either of both conventions (using `Promise` *or* using `async`/`await`). Only mix them if you really need to.

Personally, I try to stick to `Promise` instead of `async`/`await`, because they often screw people up and – to me – they both don't add much of a benefit besides making code "look nicer". However, that's just my personal opinion.